# Is struct field layout consistent with endianness in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, clr, endianness

When I first learned endianness, I was very confused at how it worked. I finally explained it to myself by the following metaphor:

On a big-endian machine, an `int[4]` would be arranged like this:

```
|       int[4]      |
|int1|int2|int3|int4|
```

While on little-endian machines, it would be laid out like

```
|       int[4]      |
|1tni|2tni|3tni|4tni|
```

That way the layout of the array would be consistent in memory, while the values themselves would be arranged differently.

**Now to the real question:** I am writing more optimized versions of `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` in my .NET library. One of the problems I have run into is the implementation of `Write(decimal)`. A decimal contains 4 `int` fields: `flags, hi, lo,` and `mid,` [in that order.](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Decimal.cs#L136-L139) So basically on your typical little-endian machine it would look like this in memory:

```
|    lamiced    |
|sgalf|ih|ol|dim|
```

My question is, how would the CLR arrange the struct on big-endian machines? Would it arrange it so that the basic layout of the decimal would be conserved, like so

```
|    decimal    |
|flags|hi|lo|mid|
```

or would it completely reverse the binary arrangement of the decimal, like

```
|    decimal    |
|mid|lo|hi|flags|
```

?

Don't have a big-endian machine nearby, otherwise I'd test it out myself.

---

**edit:** TL;DR does the following code print `-1` or `0` on big-endian machines?

```
struct Pair
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

unsafe static void Main()
{
    var p = default(Pair);
    p.a = -1;
    Console.WriteLine(*(int*)&p);
}
```

Comment: Endianness should have to do with the order of the word, not the ordering of the struct - flags should still come first. Otherwise, when deserializing a struct on one machine you'd do struct { int x, y; } whereas on another machine you'd have to do struct {int y, x; } - That's hopefully not how the world works!

Comment: No, that's not what Decimal looks like.  The CLR uses the native definition, the DECIMAL type declared in the wtypes.h SDK header.  It is much more convoluted.  It really doesn't matter, you'll never use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your *actual* question is.

Regarding the relationship between the layout of fields in a data structure and endianness, there is none. Endianness does not affect how fields in a data structure are laid out, only the order of bytes *within* a field.

I.e. in answer to this:

> does the following code print -1 or 0 on big-endian machines?

… the output will be `-1`.

But you seem to be also or instead asking about the effect of endianness on the in-memory representation of the `Decimal` type. Which is a somewhat different question.

Regarding the endianness of the `Decimal` in-memory representation, I'm not aware of any requirement that .NET provide consistent implementations of the `Decimal` type. As commenter Hans Passant points out, there are multiple ways to view the current implementation; either as the CLR code you referenced, or as the more detailed declaration seen in e.g. wtypes.h or OleDb.h (another place a `DECIMAL` type appears, which has the same format as elsewhere). But in reality, as far as .NET is concerned, you are not promised anything about the in-memory layout of the type.

I would expect, for simplicity in implementation, the fields representing the 3 32-bit mantissa components may be affected by endianness, *individually*. (The sign and scale are represented as individual bytes, so endianness would not affect those). That is, while the order of the individual 32 bit fields would remain the same — high, low, mid — the bytes within each field will be represented according to the current platform's endianness.

**But** if Microsoft for some bizarre reason decided they wanted the .NET implementation to deviate from the native implementation (seems unlikely, but let's assume it for the sake of argument) and always use little-endian for the fields even on big-endian platforms, that would be within their rights.

For that matter, they could even rearrange the fields if they wanted to: their current order appears to me to be a concession to the de facto x86 standard of little-endianness, such that on little-endian architectures the combination of low and mid 32-bit values can be treated as a single 64-bit value without swapping words, so if they decided to deviate from the wtypes.h declaration, they might well decide to just make the mantissa a single 96-bit, little-endian or big-endian value.

Again, I'm not saying these actions are in any way likely. Just that they are theoretically possible and are just easy, obvious examples (a subset of all possible examples) of why writing managed code that assumes such private implementation details is probably not a good idea.

Even if you had access to a big-endian machine that could run .NET libraries (*) and so could test the actual behavior, today's current behavior doesn't offer you any guarantees of future behavior.

(*) (I don't even know of any…pure big-endian CPUs are fairly uncommon these days, and I can't think of a single one off the top of my head that is supported by Microsoft as an actual .NET platform.)

So…

I am skeptical that it is practical to author implementations of `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` that are observably more optimized than those found in .NET already. The main reason for using these types is to handle I/O, and that necessarily means interacting with external systems that are orders of magnitude slower than the CPU that is handling the actual conversions to and from byte representations (and even the GC operations to support those conversions). Even if the existing Microsoft code were in some way hypothetically inefficient, in practice I doubt it would matter much.

But if you must implement these yourself, it seems to me that the only safe way to deal with the `Decimal` type is to use the `Decimal.GetBits()` method and `Decimal.Decimal(int[])` constructor. These use clearly-documented, endian-independent mechanisms to convert the `Decimal` type. They are based on `int`, the in-memory representation of which will of course vary according to endianness, but your code will never need to worry about that, because it will only have to deal with entire `int` values, not their byte-wise representations.

Comment: Great answer. It's worth noting though that Microsoft seems to [assume the layout of Decimal](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream/src/System/IO/UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.cs#L937-L940) in a few BCL classes, so I'm guessing it's a de facto standard of some sort.

Comment: On the usefulness... I have been wondering about this same topic in relation to the use of `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.Copy` to convert structs to byte arrays for the purpose of writing them to files. I found it's by far the simplest way to write big structs (like DIB bitmap headers) to file, but it feels like it would change the output depending on endianness of the machine.